# Is it better to shift from Navigator 1.0 to Navigator 2.0 in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, navigation, navigator

I am using still Navigator 1.0 in my all current flutter apps. If I want to migrate from Navigator 1.0 to Navigator 2.0, I found auto_route flutter package only suits for our requirements. Because many code depends on data passing between front and back screens which supports auto_route package.

So I need some suggestions to migrate from Navigator 1.0 to Navigator 2.0 now or not.
Any chances to deprecate navigator 1.0 by flutter team in future versions of flutter.

Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: So, if you're aiming to use the auto_route package, why would you migrate to Navigator 2.0? Why don't you directly use the auto_route?

Comment: Yes. My question was to use auto_route package to migrate to Navigator 2.0 or Stay back to navigator 1.0 for some time

Comment: I don't think you will need to migrate to 2.0, just go directly to the auto_route.